# Visualforce Charting rendererFn with Chart label

Tags: visualforce, javascript, visualforce-charting

I am using `rendererFn` for chartTips `"<apex:chartTips height="40" width="120" rendererFn="renderChartTip"/>"` and it changes the label for hover over the bar chart. We need the same behavior for bar chart on the Axis for apex:chartLabel:  `<apex:chartLabel display="middle"  id="barchart">` but calling the JS method same way as chartTips doesn't work in this case.

If I call the below mentioned JS method from `rendererFn` for both chartTips and apex:chartLabel, chartTips  works perfectly both nothing happens for chartLabel.

JS Method:

```
 <script>
      function renderChartTip(klass, item) {                
        var m = item.storeItem;
        this.setTitle(m.get('name'));
        this.update(''
          + '<table>'
          + '<tr><td><b></b>&nbsp;</td><td>' + m.get(item.yField) + '%</td></tr>'
          + '</table>'
        );
      }

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this rendererfn  works ? I'm unable to find any documentation on that

Comment: Voting to close because the linked duplicate has an excellent example of how to use `apex:chartLabel`.